# rand() Repeating on Archives

Tags: php, random

I'm using this to choose random images on a archive however its using the same image 2 or 3 times on each paginated archive page.

Any way to make sure it only chooses a unique image?

```
$random_image = sprintf( '%s/random/%s.png', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), rand( 6, 1 ) );
```

Edit: I think i need to use $wp_query->current_post to target each of the 6 latest posts in the loop and set a specific default image for each. Heaps of PHP but would work.

Comment: Try `mt_rand(1,6) `

Comment: 6 images yes. If no featured image, i want to show a random image from a folder of 6 but not repeat them on a archive of 6 entries

Comment: 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a pretty random image while at the same time avoiding consecutive duplicates, you can create a static array, shuffle its elements n-random times and return pop-uped value:

```
function getRandom() {
  static $arr = array();
  if (empty($arr)) {
    $arr = range(1,6);
    $count = mt_rand(1,10);
    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
      shuffle($arr);
  }
  return array_pop($arr);
}

$random_image = sprintf('%s/random/%s.png', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), getRandom());
```

Comment: Top job. Works well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

your code are random generating every time he passes to it, so the random have change to duplicate one value few times.

you can set all the values random .

```
$a = range(1,6); # total number of images
shuffle($a); # randomize

print_r($a);
```

and return the values in array.

i think it helps . :)

Comment: That returns all the same image.

Comment: it returns an array of random 1,6 ex: array(1,3,5,6,2,4) , to catch the image: you can loop in $a and set any of them on $images_arr_variable and export